# use sp_addrolemember with invoke-sqlcmd in powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, powershell

I have a very simple PowerShell script that adds a sql server login to a db role. Since I use it for SQL 2008 I need to use the `sp_addrolemember` stored procedure.

If I use t-sql in management studio like this:

```
 declare @dbrole varchar(100) 
             set @dbrole = 'db_owner'
             declare @login varchar(100)
             set @login = 'net1\vintida'


        exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = @DBRole,
        @membername =  @login
```

then it works without problem

If I use a PowerShell script like this

```
 $login = 'net1\vintida'     
      $DBrole = 'db_owner' 

     $Q3 =    "  exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = $DBRole,
    @membername =    $login  " 



Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Q3
```

then it throws the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near 'vintida'. Incorrect syntax near
>   '\'.

Howevever if I use the powershell script like this

```
$DBrole = 'db_owner'   
     $Q3 =    "exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = $DBRole,
    @membername =    'net1\vintida' "     

    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Q3
```

It works perfectly

I cannot understand why when I pass the string 'net1\vintida' into the query text using the variable `$login` it does not like the \ but I hard code the same string into the query text it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your original script doesn't include the single quotes in the final T-SQL script.

Try this:

```
$login = "'net1\vintida'"     
$DBrole = "'db_owner'" 

$Q3 = "exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = $DBRole, @membername = $login" 

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Q3
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$login = 'net1\vintida'     
$DBrole = 'db_owner' 

$Q3 = "exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = '$DBRole', @membername = '$login'" 
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Q3
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have Powershell code in the query that will be delivered and executed as SQL code.

Move the 2 Powershell assignment statements "outside" the SQL query like so:

```
$login = 'net1\vintida'     
$DBrole = 'db_owner'               

$Q3 = " exec sp_addrolemember @rolename = $DBRole,
                              @membername = $login "

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Q3
```

Comment: Did like this now the error remained complaining about the backslash only Incorrect syntax near '\' If I hardcode the $login it works

Comment: I modified the original question to include your observation